# Does every open manifold admit a function without critical point?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, singularity-theory

Assume that $M$ is  a non compact smooth manifold. Is there a smooth map $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ has no critical point?

The motivation comes from [the conversations on this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423435/fixed-point-property-for-the-total-space-of-the-canonical-line-bundle-over-mat)

Comment: I don't think so. Take the infinite genus surface with one end, for instance. Or I think a punctured torus should be a serviceable example.

Comment: @MikeMiller do you think that the infinite mobious strip is another example?

Comment: I think any example is diffeomorphic to $M \times \Bbb R$ in such a way that the function $f$ is the projection.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Not necessarily. Take any open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and let $f$ be any linear function.  Such an open subset need not be diffeomorphic to a product. Your conclusion does hold if $f$ is _proper_, though.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for pointing that out. I guess I don't really know anything about non-proper Morse functions.

Comment: @JackLee is there an smooth function on infinite mobius band without critical point?

Comment: I think the method of this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4324977/402997 applies here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interesting question. I did a little research, and found out that apparently the answer is yes: A [1961 paper by Morris Hirsch](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=124915) (Theorem 4.8) showed that every noncompact (connected) smooth manifold admits a smooth real-valued function with no critical points.

Comment: Prof.  Lee thank you very much for your help and interesting answer.

Comment: You're welcome!